# Ubuntu install button not working

Tags: system-installation

I have a computer on which Windows XP recently crashed, so I thought I would try Ubuntu. I downloaded Ubuntu 32-bit from the [website](http://www.ubuntu.com/) and burned it to a DVD using Nero.

I set the boot menu of my computer to boot from CD/DVD. After, I booted from the DVD. It was very slow (I think this was because I have IDE DVD ROM) and a purple screen launched then the try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu menu suddenly came in. I clicked 'Install Ubuntu' button several hundred times but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide more information for us to solve this problem. 
- Have you tried restarting the computer?
- Have you tried trying to boot from your thumbdrive instead?
- Have you tried using the latest .iso from ubuntu site?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not aware why you're encountering that particular problem, I'm guessing one of the possible reasons could be a damaged DVD medium and/or drive.

I can advise you to try installing from a USB Flash memory drive, if you have one available. Instructions how to do this can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).